# Where can i find the default group indicator (expandlistview, little arrow)?

Tags: android, indicator

I just want to change the group indicators color but in order to do this you need to make your own group indicator. Can somebody link me a file with the default group indicator so that i can change the color from black to white :) with gimp :). I cant find the deafault group indicator :/.

Comment: What is a "group indicator"?

Comment: the little arrow in the expandlistview

Comment: Search your drive for `expander_*.9.png`

Answer (score 1):

You can find all the Android resources in the Sdk

Check $ANDROID_SDK_HOME/platforms/android-xx/data/res

Comment: Is there a way to programmatically access those?